# Vim: How to delete between the cursor and the first character of the line?

Tags: vim

How to delete till the first character of the line ? In the line below, for example, with the cursor near the end as indicated, delete backwards until the first `$`.

I have this line:

```
[space][space][space]$entity->setPositionBrand(count($qb->getResult())[my_cursor_here] + 1);
```

After deletion, I want this:

```
[space][space][space] + 1);
```

Comment: Your question isn't formulated very clearly. Do you mean to delete all the whitespace characters prior to the first `$` sign?

Comment: @EdwardL. no. I want to keep them.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Your question is specifically asking "how to delete". You need to specify exactly which part of the line you're looking to delete.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the line looks like currently and another of what you want it to look like after deletion?

Comment: @EdwardL. I think is clear enough: "till the first character of the line".

Comment: Lol, your example now makes it clear, but "till the first character of the line" is grossly inaccurate considering you're deleting a chunk of text in the middle of the line. I think what you want to do is too specific and may have to be done through regex-based delete keybinding.

Comment: You ask one thing in the title, then another thing in the body and the sample illustrates yet another question. Could you make it clearer?

Comment: If the end of the line is always the same then change your logic to delete, vim people get unreasonably unhappy when you use words as per English :) , to the match at the end    eg something like %s/\$\S\+\s/ /g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a standard vim motion that goes exactly to the first non-whitespace character on the line. It's `^`

So you only need to type `d^`.

Comment: Could you elaborate exactly how you'll get the `[space][space][space] + 1);` line after typing `d^`? I did it in vim and it just deletes the whitespace characters till the first character, not the second line specified in OP. I think he actually wants to keep those white space characters.

Comment: where did you put your cursor? it seems to me you'd put it at the beginning of the line, while it should be far to the right before the plus sign.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for the clarification. I would edit your answer to clarify that part for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not as succinct as Vladimir's answer (which is a better solution), but for the record, here's how you could achieve the same with visual mode.

`v0wx`

- `v` Enter visual mode.
- `0` Move to the beginning of the line.
- `w` Move to first word.
- `x` delete characters in visual selection.

Any amount of whitespace counts as a word.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general solution, you would probably need some sort of regex-based keybinding. But, you can accomplish what you want with these key combinations:

- Put your cursor on the first `$` sign.
- `d` `12` `e`

The second key sequence deletes characters from the position of your cursor up to the end of the twelfth word, which will result in exactly the line you want.